# NLP algorithm and data analysis

Tags: python, nlp, data-science, model-fitting

I am very new to analyzing text data and extracting information out of it. I need some suggestion help from the communnity. The dataset is from the job website where 'id' denotes the job id, 'abstract' denotes title, 'content' denotes the body and so on.

This data have the columns

```
Index(['id', 'title', 'abstract', 'content', 'metadata'], dtype='object')
```

Head of the data looks like the following. (1)

```
    id  title   abstract    content     metadata    clean_content
0   38915469    Recruitment Consultant  We are looking for someone to focus purely on ...   <HTML><p>Are you looking to join a thriving bu...   {'standout': {'bullet1': 'Join a Sector that i...   Are you looking to join a thriving business th...
1   38934839    Computers Salesperson - Coburg  Passionate about exceptional customer service?...   <HTML><p>&middot;&nbsp;&nbsp;Casual hours as r...   {'additionalSalaryText': 'Attractive Commissio...   middotnbspnbspCasual hours as required transit...
2   38946054    Senior Developer | SA   Readifarians are known for discovering the lat...   <HTML><p>Readify helps organizations innovate ...   {'standout': {'bullet1': 'Design, develop, tes...   Readify helps organizations innovate with tech...
3   38833950    Senior Commercial Property Manager | Leading T...   ~ Rare opportunity for a Senior PM to step int...   <HTML><p><strong>WayPoint Recruitment&nbsp;</s...   {'additionalSalaryText': '$140k + Car Park - C...   WayPoint Recruitmentnbsphave partnered up with...
4   38856271    Technology Manager | Travel Industry    Rare opportunity for an experienced Technology...   <HTML>This is a key role within a market leadi...   {'standout': {'bullet1': 'Lead overarching str...   This is a key role within a market leading wi...
```

The second set of data related to the above is given as follows, where it has job id, , job viewing platform and I feel most important column 'kind' has two labels 'A' for applied and 'V' for view.

(2)

```
    event_datetime  resume_id   job_id  event_platform  kind
0   2021-05-01T08:42:05     158655  38820886    IOS_APP     V
1   2021-05-01T08:42:05     158655  38901970    IOS_APP     V
2   2021-05-01T08:42:05     158655  38919645    IOS_APP     A
3   2021-05-01T08:42:05     158655  38928402    IOS_APP     V
4   2021-05-01T08:42:05     158655  38847632    IOS_APP     A
```

The first thing I did groupby job_id and kind

```
ndf = df.groupby(["job_id","kind"]).count()['resume_id'].reset_index().pivot(index='job_id', columns = 'kind')
(3)
```

The above code returns a data frame that is indexed by job_id and two columns one representing A and the other V.

There are more information about the job in the 'metadata' columns like 'location' etc, I could not use it as I don't now how to extract. I have only use 'content' column to make the prediction.

I have done some textual analysis using nltk, my the main aim is to give a model to predict given a job if it's applied to the view. Is there exist some similar notebook I can follow or some suggestions.

What other interesting facts I can get out of the data? Or any other model I can predict out of the data? I never use the event platform data that is the data mentioning job applicant using IOS_APP or Anroid_APP or web. Any discussion is very welcome.

Comment: Please add a relevant language tag to your question.

Comment: I see, sorry so what tags should I use?

Comment: @GGT, language = Python, Java, etc. Looks like it is python based on your dataframe example.